# Conditional formatting text in Excel without specifying the text to highlight?

Tags: excel, string, text, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight a table where any strings are highlighted one colour if they're the same. The table is large so i don't want to specify every string, can excel do something like this automatically? As in I would like excel to identify every string and apply the same colour to strings that are the same without having to input every unique value

Tried the conditional formatting menu, cannot see how to do it without specifying every string.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Conditional values: Duplicate values for this:

[image]

A simple example, but I use it for checking duplicate sof 6 digit numbers.

And it works with words as well.